# PHP mssql_fetch_array and get database data type

Tags: php, json, database, types

I have a category Table:

categoryId: int

categoryName: string

I retrieved my data from Database using:

```
while($rows[] = mysql_fetch_array($result,MSSQL_ASSOC)){}
```

And I want to display the result in json format.

```
$response = array('success' => true, 'data' => $rows);
echo json_encode($response);
```

It returns:

```
{"success":true,"data":[{"categoryId":"1","categoryName":"Car"}]}
```

Is it possible to return the categoryId as integer ({"categoryId":1) instead of string?
I know that mssql_fetch_array will return string. Any good way to retain the database data type when I json_encode my fetch result?

Comment: Please stop using the deprecated [mysql extension](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated). Switch to [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://ch2.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Comment: Note: I rolled back the edit to add the mysql tag, since it is not clear if this question is about mysql or mssql (I tend to assume the latter).

Answer (score -1):

in [`mysql_fetch_array`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) documentation , it is clearly written

> Returns an array of **strings** that corresponds to the fetched row, or
>   FALSE if there are no more rows. The type of returned array depends on
>   how result_type is defined.

so you better change the datatype by **[type casting](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php#language.types.typecasting)**

```
$foo = (int) $bar;
```

Comment: I heard intval is better but that's my $.02